# Attach TEdit boxes to a TDBgrid column

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tdbgrid

How can I attach the edit boxes to the corresponding grid columns, so it will change width when the user change the column width and move around when the user change the order of DBGraid columns.

[image: Example of the form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know that the column widths have changed then you can override `ColWidthsChanged`. I'm not aware of a corresponding event.

For detecting columns having moved you can either override `ColumnMoved` or attach a handler to the `OnColumnMoved` event.

Comment: the TColumn has now Left properties, do I have to calculate the new edit1.Left in ColumnMoved ?

Comment: You'll need to calculate it from the width properties. You'll need to allow for any borders too.